# Where are programming languages published?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

I have read that a number of new programming languages are created each year, however I have never seen a single one. Where exactly are these things published? Is there some site out there that keeps track of them?

(I don't have any intention to learn such languages - I am only interested)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's one place that's generally agreed upon. A lot will depend on the type of language and on the source. Quite a few are invented by university students, and generally published in that student's thesis, dissertation, etc. Many companies have some sort of technical journal or other to publish their researchers' results. If it's somebody doing it on their own time, they might well publish it on their blog. If they decide to make the implementation an open source project, they might well publish it someplace like BitBucket, SourceForge, Github, etc. If it's (for example) a functional language, they might publish it someplace like *Lambda the Ultimate*. In some cases, it'll fit more than one category, and be published several of those places at once.

Comment: Only place I'd add to this list is reddit.com/r/programming

Answer (score 5):

> Where exactly are these things published?

Many places.  Start with source forge, git hub and any other site that supports open source code.  Go to University research sites.  Read the Communications of the ACM and the IEEE Computer Society magazines.  Then read the various ACM publications on programming languages.

It's not secret.  It's very, very public.

> Is there some site out there that keeps track of them?

No.

Wikipedia, however, tends to accumulate this kind of information. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_programming_languages

Answer (score 0):

Felix is described at [felix-lang.org](http://felix-lang.org/), but the source is on [GitHub.com](https://github.com/felix-lang/felix). So even one language can't be said to be published in one place :)